# How to add drive/partition-icon to the launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, drive

My dualboot-system (win7 / ubuntu 12.04) has a ntfs-formatted partition called "/share" for files I use both in win7 and ubuntu (e.g. pictures, music etc.).

I'd like to have a symbol of this drive in the launcher. 
But although the partition is mounted (Mount point: /media/share) and shown in the left side bar of a folder, there is no Icon in the launcher!
**How can I add this Icon to the launcher?**

(CompizConfig Setting manager >> ubuntu unity plugin >> Experimental >> show devices always" will only show  win-Partition, not the /share -partition)

Answer (score 14):

I have a hd named "backup" which I "accidentally" removed. ;)

I added the backup-hd-icon to the launcher by

1. Clicked the dash
2. Typed backup
3. Dragged the icon to the launcher

Important is that you don't drag the folder, you want to search for the hd icon

Comment: Nice trick. It worked fine for me on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 5):

Create a `.desktop` file and place it in `.local/share/applications/`

As your device is mounted at `/media/share`, lets name the file as `mediashare.desktop`

The content of the file will be as follows:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Shared Media
Comment=Shared Media
Exec=nautilus /media/share
Icon=system-file-manager
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=mediashare
```

Once this is done, run the following in your terminal

```
gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites
```

A list of icons on the launcher will be displayed like this:
`['unity://running-apps', 'unity://expo-icon', 'unity://devices']`

Now add the mediashare.desktop to it like this:
`['unity://running-apps', 'unity://expo-icon', 'unity://devices', 'mediashare.desktop']`

Now copy the above and run the following in the terminal

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "['unity://running-apps', 'unity://expo-icon', 'unity://devices', 'mediashare.desktop']"
```

Mind the quotes.

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, type `unity` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to refresh unity.

Comment: That's not too hard, but I'm still surprised there's not an utility to make shortcuts about anything, like on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open the "dash" (first option in the launcher bar).
2. Type your drive name which you want to add in your launcher.
3. Drag the drive icon to the launcher.

Comment: Comment to both editor and original poster: AskUbuntu has automatically numbered lists.  Just use [space]number[dot][space] and then type your text.  Even if the numbers are not in the correct order when typing, they will come out looking great! for more information: http://askubuntu.com/editing-help

Comment: Simple and works like a charm

Comment: This answer has the same contents like the one above by axel112!

Answer (score 1):

Click on ''Files'' in Launcher.
from the left side menu bar click on the drive you want to launch.
now the drive opens and contents are displayed. at the same time that drive is seen in the unity launcher. Right click on that drive and click on "Lock to launcher''. Done !!