# How to change device icons in launcher?

Tags: unity, 13.04, launcher

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 and I have several hard drives in my computer and all appear with the same icon in the launcher.
Is it possible to modify their icons one by one or at least change their color to better find what I'm looking for?

[image]

Comment: Good Question. It can help in future:)

Comment: does this not work: http://askubuntu.com/questions/235805/how-to-add-drive-partition-icon-to-the-launcher Just make several .desktop files and change their icon.

Comment: i tried to follow that solutions but it doesn't work, at least for me

Comment: check this out http://askubuntu.com/questions/70867/how-to-customize-label-the-hard-drive-icons-in-the-launcher

Comment: @Stormvirux i tried with one external usb drive. It doesn't change the launcher icon, but i've noticed that if you navigate to /media/youruser/ you will see something like this http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/827/tbtq.png/
The little black disk icon is the one that i tried to add to de device

Comment: It seems (I didn't notice/mind until now) recently Nautilus stopped using Windows files **autorun.inf** / **desktop.ini** to display a custom drive icon instead of the default one in the current icon theme, while still using it for custom folder emblem - strange :/)

Comment: what about this one http://askubuntu.com/questions/80627/how-can-i-change-the-icon-of-an-application-in-the-unity-launcher

Comment: @Stormvirux, i can't get it to work for device

Answer (score 16):

You can use udev rules to match with your devices and then assign an icon.

#### NOTE: In this example I will change the icons for 3 devices, usb pendrive, partition with Opensuse and a partition (Raid) with Linux Mint.

[image]

---

## For Ubuntu 12.10 and Newer.

**1)** I have 3 icons in my Desktop for each device *(2 png and 1 svg images)*, copy the 3 icons to the `/usr/share/pixmaps` folder and give them perms.

[image]

- `cd ~/Desktop`
- `sudo cp linuxmint.svg pendrive.png opensuse.png /usr/share/pixmaps/`
- `cd /usr/share/pixmaps/`
- `sudo chmod 644 linuxmint.svg pendrive.png opensuse.png`

**2)** List the usb pendrive to know the **"idVendor"** and **"idProduct"**, in a Terminal type:

- `lsusb`

[image]

Write down the numbers after "ID".

**In my example:**

> Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0930:6545 Toshiba Corp. Kingston DataTraveler
>   102 Flash Drive / HEMA Flash Drive 2 GB / PNY Attache 4GB Stick

The **"idVendor"** is **0930** and the **"idProduct"** is **6545**
I'm going to match that info with the "ATTRS{idVendor}" and "ATTRS{idProduct}" keys for my usb Pendrive.

**3)** Make sure your partitions are mounted, then list your partitions and find the attributes.

- `df -h`

**In my example:**

> `/dev/sdc3                  289G  6.3G  282G   3%
>   /media/hermes/OpenSuse`
>
> `/dev/mapper/pdc_cjjfccgf3  296G   68G  213G  25%
>   /media/hermes/Linux-Mint-Raid`

**4)** List the attributes of the OpenSuse partition with *"udevadm info -a -n device name"*

- `udevadm info -a -n /dev/sdc3`

You can use this info to match the partition.

[image]

In this example I'm going to match with the **"KERNEL"** and **"SUBSYSTEM"** keys for the OpenSuse.

> KERNEL=="sdc3", SUBSYSTEM=="block"

Write down this info.

**5)** In case of the *Linux-Mint-Raid* partition, I'm goin to match the rules with the **"SUBSYSTEM"**, **"ATTR{size}"** and the **"ID_FS_LABEL"** ENV variable.

List the attributes and variables of the Linux-Mint-Raid partition with *"udevadm info -a -n device name"* and *"udevadm info -q all -n device name"*.

- `udevadm info -a -n /dev/mapper/pdc_cjjfccgf3`
- `udevadm info -q all -n /dev/mapper/pdc_cjjfccgf3`

[image]

[image]

---

#### Creating the udev rule.

**6)** Go to the */etc/udev/rules.d* folder and create a file with your favorite editor. 
eg: *99-devices-icons.rules*

- `cd /etc/udev/rules.d/`
- `sudo nano 99-devices-icons.rules`

Write down the info to match each device and then with the **ENV{UDISKS_ICON_NAME}** you will assign an icon.

**In my example:**

> ATTRS{idVendor}=="0930", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6545",
>   ENV{UDISKS_ICON_NAME}="pendrive" KERNEL=="sdc3", SUBSYSTEM=="block",
>   ENV{UDISKS_ICON_NAME}="opensuse" SUBSYSTEM=="block",
>   ATTR{size}=="629145600", ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}=="Linux-Mint-Raid",
>   ENV{UDISKS_ICON_NAME}="linuxmint"

In nano you can save the changes with:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>O</kbd>,<kbd>Enter</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>X</kbd>

**7)** To refresh the udev rules and see the changes, type in a Terminal window:

- `sudo udevadm trigger`

[image]

---

## For Ubuntu 12.04.

The same but you should assign the icon with **ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_ICON_NAME}** instead ENV{UDISKS_ICON_NAME}

> ATTRS{idVendor}=="0930", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6545",
>   ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_ICON_NAME}="pendrive" 
> KERNEL=="sdc3",
>   SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_ICON_NAME}="opensuse"
>   
> SUBSYSTEM=="block", ATTR{size}=="629145600",
>   ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}=="Linux-Mint-Raid",
>   ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_ICON_NAME}="linuxmint"

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: Aargh...! I thought the answer was `right click --> "Set icon"`. But I forgot, this isn't windows, it's ubuntu!   but +1.

Comment: Note the assignments in the rules above are "=" (single equals) and the tests for equality are "==".

Comment: Your instructions were really great! I was able to use them to assign custom icons to my Windows partition, external hard drive, flash drive, and Kindle. If only the launcher just used Nautilus’s custom icons, this wouldn’t have been necessary!

I’m having one problem though: **how do I modify the icon for my phone**? No matter what attribute I use, it seems I cannot create a rule specifically for my Samsung phone.

Thanks!

Comment: This method still works in 16.04, though I still use UDISKS_ICON_NAME