# How to change icon for mounted devices in Unity/Nautilus?

Tags: unity, mount, launcher, icons

When I mount a my phone, Unity set this icon (or one like it) in its Launcher:
`/usr/share/icons/Humanity/devices/48/multimedia-player.svg`

Nautilus shows this icon (or one like it): `/usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable/devices/multimedia-player-symbolic.svg`

[image]

The thing is I'm tired of looking at a silly generic multimedia player icon for my phone.  I want to add my own phone icon.

I could perhaps add my own `multimedia-player.png` and `multimedia-player-symbolic.png` in perhaps `~/.local/share/icons` and hope they get precedence over the system icons.

But I'd rather fix the root of the problem and have my phone detected as a "phone" instead of a "multimedia-player" which seems to me the case.

My questions are:

1. How do I change the icon for my phone?
2. Where is this "multimedia-player" device class detected? And where can I specify my own?  (I assume some udev usb vendor id configuration rule, but I cannot find any).
3. Where is the icon associated with device class?  (If this is really what's going on)

Comment: Look at this answer please: http://askubuntu.com/a/333817/367990

Comment: I can't seem to make it work on Ubuntu 14.04.  Has this approach been confirmed on 14.04?  I'd still like to know where the "multimedia-player" icon is set by default.  I can't seem to find any udev rules for it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Replace the existing icon files with the icon file of your choice (I have a steam-punk truck for all my USB HDDs (defined in `fstab`) and a steam-punk Zeppelin for USB sticks. (my ancient phone gets detected as a USB drive, so I didn't bother changing that one neither)
2. Yes, udev! No don't ask: I didn't bother, I used solution 1 (much less work).
3. `/usr/share/pixmaps` and its subdirectories.

You can also have [a look here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/328488/how-to-change-device-icons-in-launcher/333817#333817) for more advanced options.