# Accidentally removed a drive shortcut from the Launcher. How do I put it back?

Tags: launcher, shortcuts

I've got three partitions on my system, and I accidentally removed a shortcut to the first Ubuntu partition from the Launcher. How do I put it back?

(At least, I assume it was a shortcut, as the partition is still here. They're called shortcuts in Ubuntu, right?)

Also, is there a way to rename my drives? I keep getting confused as to which drive is which.

Comment: 1.Goto `/media/username` it consists of mounted partitions.You can rename the partitions by right click on the specified partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they are called launcher desktop files ( [Where are the Unity Launcher .desktop files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40931/where-are-the-unity-launcher-desktop-files) )

Open the disc from within Nautilus and the desktop launcher will be back. All you then need to do is rightclick and fix it to the launcher.

Also see:

- [How to add drive/partition-icon to the launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235805/how-to-add-drive-partition-icon-to-the-launcher)

> Also, is there a way to rename my drives? I keep getting confused as to which drive is which.

You can label discs:

- [How to edit label of USB drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194510/how-to-edit-label-of-usb-drive)

You can also do this from the properties option when rightclicking the disc.

Comment: I'm opening it in Nautilus but the window is under files, it's not under its own separate, uh, tab?, on the launcher.

Comment: @AndrewPampuch updated with a manual method

Comment: There's no applications folder in /local/share. Are there multiple local folders?

Sorry, I'm VERY new to this, it's really confusing when you're used to filepaths starting with C:\ all the time, so I have no idea where to really start from.

Comment: There is! Mind the . in front of it...that makes it a hidden file so if you do this from nautilus press control+h in your home dir ;)

Comment: You know what...I just realized you can do exactly what I want to do just by opening "Files." Thanks anyway, though.

Answer (score 2):

Now, if you want to reset the settings, run this command in a terminal:

```
gsettings reset com.canonical.Unity.Devices blacklist
```

Also works with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Source: [How can I remove launcher drive icons?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195988/how-can-i-remove-launcher-drive-icons)